# Copy multiple hex arrays into one in C

Tags: c, arrays, concatenation

My problem is, i have 5 hexadecimal arrays and want to combine them.

```
unsigned char sc1[] = "\xfc\xe8\x82\x00\x00\x00\x60\x89\xe5\x31\xc0";        
unsigned char ip[] = "\xc0\xa8\x00\x01"; // IP 192.168.0.1  
unsigned char sc2[] = "\x68\x02\x00";
unsigned char port[] = "\x04\xd2"; // PORT 1234    
unsigned char sc3[] = "\x89\xe6\x50\x50\x50\x50\x40\x50\x40\x50"
```

Of course, the order shouldnt change (network byte order i guess) :P I tried it with memcpy

```
unsigned char result[sizeof(sc1) + sizeof(ip) + sizeof(sc2) + sizeof(port) + sizeof(sc3)];

memcpy( result, sc1, sizeof(sc1) );
memcpy( result + sizeof(sc1), ip, sizeof(ip) );
memcpy( result + sizeof(sc1) + sizeof(ip), sc2, sizeof(sc2) );
memcpy( result + sizeof(sc1) + sizeof(ip) + sizeof(sc2), port, sizeof(port) );
memcpy( result + sizeof(sc1) + sizeof(ip) + sizeof(sc2) + sizeof(port), sc3, sizeof(sc3) );
```

and so on for every array but when i try to print it

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(result); i++) {
    printf("%d ", result[i]);
}
```

the result is just nonsense so i stopped fiddling around and hope you can help me out.

EDIT: Sorry folks, i got it, im so stupid!!! Of course i have to use `%x`

```
printf("%x ", result[i]);
```

Comment: Those aren't "hexadecimal" arrays. They're just chars that you chose to represent that way textually. The data is the same as if you had specified a comma separated list of decimal or octal literals.

Comment: I know, but i dont need a list of comma separated values, i need it represented that way. Thats it!

Comment: You might explain a bit more in which way it is "just nonsense" for your next questions.

Comment: Didnt my edit explain it? I used the wrong representatin so i've seen the wrong values.. Its solved anyway..

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` on each one of those arrays is +1 larger than you think it is. Because each string also contains the null terminating zero (as any string would).  And that increases each array by 1 bytes as well.  For example, `sizeof(ip1)` is 5, not 4.

Quick and dirty hack to your program is to subtract 1 form each `sizeof()` calculation.  Like this:

```
unsigned char result[sizeof(sc1) + sizeof(ip) + sizeof(sc2) + sizeof(port) + sizeof(sc3) - 5];

memcpy(result, sc1, sizeof(sc1)-1);
memcpy(result + sizeof(sc1)-1, ip, sizeof(ip)-1);
memcpy(result + sizeof(sc1)-1 + sizeof(ip)-1, sc2, sizeof(sc2)-1);
memcpy(result + sizeof(sc1)-1 + sizeof(ip)-1 + sizeof(sc2)-1, port, sizeof(port)-1);
memcpy(result + sizeof(sc1)-1 + sizeof(ip)-1 + sizeof(sc2)-1 + sizeof(port)-1, sc3, sizeof(sc3)-1);


for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(result); i++) {
    printf("%02x ", result[i]);  // %x, not %d to print hex
}
```

Outputs:

```
fc e8 82 00 00 00 60 89 e5 31 c0 c0 a8 00 01 68 02 00 04 d2 89 e6 50 50 50 50 40 50 40 50
```